# Error using Inheritance

Tags: c#

i have created a class and with that class i passed constructor and then i made that class abstract class, but when i want to get 1 attribute of the abstract class from the inherit class it showing some error can not take argument 0

```
public class Device1
{
    public int dwMachineNumber;
    public int dwBaudrate;
    public int dwCommPort;
    public string dwIPAddress;
    public int dwPort;
    public int dwPassWord;

    public Device1(int dwMachineNumber)
    {
        this.dwMachineNumber = dwMachineNumber;
    }

    public Device1(int dwMachineNumber, int dwBaudrate, int dwCommPort, string dwIPAddress, int dwPort, int dwPassWord)
    {
        this.dwMachineNumber = dwMachineNumber;
        this.dwBaudrate = dwBaudrate;
        this.dwCommPort = dwCommPort;
        this.dwIPAddress = dwIPAddress;
        this.dwPort = dwPort;
        this.dwPassWord = dwPassWord;
    }

}

public class EnableMachine : Device1
{
    public int Device_Busy; //if 0 busy and 1 not busy 

    public EnableMachine(int dwMachineNumber, int Device_Busy)
    {
        this.Device_Busy = Device_Busy;
        this.dwMachineNumber = dwMachineNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what your question is?

Comment: `public int Device_Busy;` looks really strange. I don't see any abstract classes either...

Comment: it is just a attribute of a inherit class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class EnableMachine : Device1
{
    public int Device_Busy; //if 0 busy and 1 not busy 

    public EnableMachine(int dwMachineNumber, int Device_Busy) 
        : base(dwMachineNumber)
    {
        this.Device_Busy = Device_Busy;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

When calling the constructor of a derived class, it also tries to call the constructor of the base class. Since you just had:

```
public EnableMachine(int dwMachineNumber, int Device_Busy)
{...}
```

it by default tries to call the parameterless constructor `Device()` **but** Device1 does not have a parameterless constructor; hence the error "..does not contain a method accepting 0 arguments".

You need to **tell** it to use the constructor accepting the *dwMachineNumber* argument by adding the line

```
: base(dwMachineNumber)
```

to your derived class's constructor. So, effectively, when you instantiate the derived class, it takes the *dwMachineNumber* argument and trunks it through to the base class's constructor.

Comment: @Mano: See my edited answer. Jon Skeet had the most clear answer, actually.

Answer (score 4):

This won't compile, because your `EnableMachine` constructor is effectively:

```
public EnableMachine(int dwMachineNumber, int Device_Busy)
    : base() // Call base class parameterless constructor
{
    this.Device_Busy = Device_Busy;
    this.dwMachineNumber = dwMachineNumber;
}
```

Now the base class doesn't *have* a parameterless constructor.

The code should be:

```
public EnableMachine(int dwMachineNumber, int Device_Busy)
    : base(dwMachineNumber)
{
    this.Device_Busy = Device_Busy;
}
```

As for the rest of the code: I would *strongly* encourage you not to use public fields, not to use underscores in public member names, not to use pseudo-Hungarian naming (e.g. the `dw` prefix), and to use more descriptive class names.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call the base constructor in the derived class constructor:

```
public EnableMachine(int dwMachineNumber, int Device_Busy)
    : base(dwMachineNumber)
{
    this.Device_Busy = Device_Busy;
}
```

Notice that you no longer need to set the `dwMachineNumber` in the derived constructor as this is done in the base class.